# Why can't I get input from the ifstream?

Tags: c++-cli, ifstream

I am trying to read in a text file for a maze program. The input is something like:

```
10 10
OO+E+OO+++
O++O+O+OOO
OOOOOO+O+O
+++++O++OO
OOO+OOO+O+
O+O+O+++O+
O+O+OOO+OO
++O+++O++O
O+OOOOO++O
O+O++O+OOO
```

When the user click on the open button, this opens a open file dialog box

```
     {
        openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = "C:\Desktop;";
        openFileDialog1->Filter = "Maze files (*.DAT)|*.DAT";

        if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == ::DialogResult::OK)
        {
            char filename[1024];
            for (int i = 0; i < openFileDialog1->FileName->Length; i++)
            {
                filename[i] = openFileDialog1->FileName[i];
            }
            ifstream ifs;
            ifs.open(filename); // NULL terminate this
            maze = new Maze( panel1, ifs);
            ifs.close();
        }
     }
```

the following is the maze constructor

```
Maze::Maze( Panel ^ drawingPanel, ifstream & ifs )
{

    try
    {
        valid = false;
        ifs >> width >> height;
        int temp = width;
        drawingPanel->Size.Width = width;
        drawingPanel->Size.Height = height;

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) // height is always nothing
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                if (orig[j][i] == DEADEND ||
                     orig[j][i] == OPEN ||
                     orig[j][i] == EXIT )
                    ifs >> orig[j][i];  // NULLS????
                else
                    throw 'D'; // i had to throw something....so i threw the D /* make a slit class and throw the D there? slit.fill(D); */
            }
        // this should be last
        panel = drawingPanel;
        valid = true;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        valid = false;
        MessageBox::Show( "Not a proper maze file!" );
    }
}
```

when the program runs:  ifs >> width >> height    width and height do not get set correctly.

I have searched this site for this problem and have not been able to find anything that has helped. Sorry for my inexperience, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why the big `if()` statement deciding whether or not to read a maze element?

Comment: You should check the result of inputting from the file.  There may be an error there generated by the OS.

Comment: Did `ifs.open(...)` succeed? You never check `ifs.good()`.

Comment: This is C++/CLI. Please for the love of god, stop this. If you like .NET, use C#. If you like C++, use C++. But don't use the combination of the cryptic C++ syntax and .NET runtime disadvantages. C++/CLI is a tool for people who *have* to use it. And then it's godsent. But please, if you don't know a hundred percent you are one of those people, it's not too late to decide for either C# *or* C++.

Comment: All of that code for just this:?  http://ideone.com/7xhwe5  Just replace `cin` with an ifstream, and that's the only change needed.  Once you read in the maze, then you figure out if it's any good or not.

Comment: The "small picture" answer to your question is that your godawful "cast each wchar_t to char" string is not null-terminated, so your ifstream doesn't correctly open the file. And you aren't checking whether it succeeded (ifstream doesn't throw on failure).

Answer (score 1):

You'e program very ugly : don't know if you're programming in C or C++ or C++/CLI, or try to mix the 3...

Because you use Windows Form projet, i will give you a .Net solution for read a file, it's not the better solution but this does not mix things.

First for read the file, on a first window :

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    openFileDialog1->Filter = "Maze Files (*.dat) | *.dat";
    if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == ::DialogResult::OK)
    {
        String ^fileName = openFileDialog1->FileName;
        IO::StreamReader ^myMazeFile = gcnew IO::StreamReader(fileName);
        String ^content = myMazeFile->ReadToEnd();
        richTextBox1->Text = content;
        myMazeFile->Close();
        // display button for open second form wich draw maze
        button2->Visible = true;
    }
}
```

now we have our file content, so we pass it to a second form who will draw the maze :

```
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    String ^content = richTextBox1->Text;
    Maze ^frm = gcnew Maze(content);
    frm->Show();
}
```

Second window, create overload constructor :

```
Maze(String ^contentMap)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    String ^dimension = getWords(contentMap, 2);
    array<String ^> ^coordsString = dimension->Split(gcnew array<Char> {' '});
    m_width = Convert::ToInt32(coordsString[0]);
    m_height = Convert::ToInt32(coordsString[1]);
    panel1->Width = m_width;
    panel1->Height = m_height;
}
```

getWords method :

```
String ^getWords(String ^input, int numWords)
{
    try
    {
        int words = numWords;
        for (int i = 0; i < input->Length; ++i)
        {
            if (input[i] == ' ' ||input[i] == '\n')
                words--;
            if (words == 0)
            {
                return input->Substring(0, i);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ^ex)
    {
        // ...
    }
    return String::Empty;
}
```

You have your dimension in full .Net (private member m_width and m_height).